# Mysql count works not in case of curdate

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query which counts the customer's PPPOE breaks. It works perfectly in this case - in the output file I can see the customer's name and how many time his PPPOE connection was dropped:

```
   select
   username,
   count(username) as db,
   DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d')
   from radius_db.radacct
   where DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-01-02'
   group by username
   order by db desc;
```

I tried to make it automatic so I modified the `WHERE` statement, but in this case in the output I see only the customers whose PPPOE was only dropped once and the others not.

```
    select
    username,
    count(username) as db,
    DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d')
    from radius_db.radacct
    where DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-%d')
    group by username
    order by db desc into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/pppoe-"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d%m%s')
   , ".txt'";
```

Comment: which data type is acctstarttime ??

Comment: It is "datetime".

Comment: i have already posted  an aswer  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you acctstarttime column is  datetime column you could filter by date() and curdate()

```
 select
    username,
    count(username) as db,
    DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d')
    from radius_db.radacct
    where DATE(acctstarttime) =curdate()
    group by username
    order by db desc into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/pppoe-"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d%m%s')
   , ".txt'";
```

and be careful .. because where DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-01-02' mean 2018 January 2 not 2018 February 1 as curdate()

Comment: the same result, i dont see in the file a costumers who has more than one pppoe drops/day!

Comment: be careful  .. because where DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-01-02' mean 2018 January 2  not 2018 February 1 as curdate()